# How can I randomly select options in a Laravel project with cron job?

Tags: laravel-10

I want the exam questions to change automatically in the code line of my Laravel project. Since I am new to Laravel, I don't know how to achieve this. Is there anyone who can explain?

The code line where the selection of questions is made is this.

```
                                <tbody>

                                @php $total_marks = 0; @endphp
                                @foreach($question_banks as $question_bank)

                                    @php $total_marks += $question_bank->mark; @endphp
                                    <tr class="abc">
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="primary_checkbox d-flex  "
                                                   for="question{{ @$question_bank->id}}">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="questions[]"
                                                       id="question{{ @$question_bank->id}}"
                                                       value="{{ @$question_bank->id}}"
                                                       {{in_array(@$question_bank->id, @$already_assigned)? 'checked': ''}}
                                                       class="common-checkbox question">
                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{@$question_bank->questionGroup !=""?@$question_bank->questionGroup->title:""}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @php
                                                if (@$question_bank->type == "M") {
                                               echo trans('quiz.Multiple Choice');
                                               } elseif (@$question_bank->type == "S") {
                                               echo trans('quiz.Short Answer');
                                               } elseif (@$question_bank->type == "L") {
                                               echo trans('quiz.Long Answer');
                                               } else {
                                               echo trans('quiz.Fill In The Blanks');
                                               }
                                            @endphp
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(strip_tags($question_bank->question),50) !!}</td>
                                        <td>{{@$question_bank->marks}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @if (!empty($question_bank->image))
                                                <img style="max-width: 150px;" src="{{asset($question_bank->image)}}">
                                            @endif
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
```

How can I refresh the checkbox section within the code every hour?

I haven't tried anything yet.